# How to get the count of products registered per day in the last 7 days using Laravel

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I have a table with products.
In this table I have a column with the date of the products' cacastrast.

I was looking at Carbon and wanted to implement a method in my Laravel application that showed the quantity of products in the last 7 days.

In Java I used this method:

```
public Date getSevenDays() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.DATE) - 7);
        Date lastSevenDays = cal.getTime();
        return lastSevenDays;
    }
```

how could i adapt using Carbon so that he returned the quantity of products registered in the last 7 days?
the return would be an array like this:

```
[6,4,18,11,5,16,7]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just fetch all records in last 7 days and group by date

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$productsByDay = Product::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(7))
                ->groupBy('date')
                ->orderBy('date', 'DESC')
                ->get([
                DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'),
                DB::raw('COUNT(*) as "products"')
])->pluck('products','date')->toArray();
//I recommend key by date, so that if you have no products on a date, you still have the dates in order.

//you can pass timezone in now() method of carbon, if you timezone is different than the timezone stored in DB
```

Comment: it worked ... but I would like only the quantity ... what is showing up is the date and quantity.

Comment: ->pluck('products') Remove 'date' (2nd argument to pluck method) which is used as key for creating array

Comment: Be aware of dates which has no products, as you may end up with array of 5 elements and not know which date is missing.